# How to cast generic Class type into an another generic Class type in Java

Tags: java, class, generics, casting

This is what I want:

```
interface A {}
abstract class B implements A {}
class C extends B { /*few fields*/ }
class D extends B { /*few different fields*/ }

public void doSomething(Class<A> clazz) {
    if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(B)) {
        doSomethingElse((Class<? extends B>)clazz); // casting is good, but cannot pass this way to doSomethingElse
    }
}

public <T extends B> void doSomethingElse(Class<T> clazz) {
    if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(C)) {
        // do something with C fields
    } else if(clazz.isAssignableFrom(D)) {
        // do something with D fields
    }
}
```

But obviously I cannot cast the class type this way.

Is there a way to do it? I am very curious...

Thanks!

Comment: Since B is an actual type, there is nothing stopping you from passing `B.class` to doSomethingElse instead of trying to cast `clazz`. i.e. `doSomethingElse(B.class)`

Comment: the example was not correct, I updated it with class C and D

Comment: it smells a bit like a design flaw... what actually do you want do with the fields? also how do you access the fields? Will you create a new instance via reflections? It's honestly a bit too vague to give an appropriate answer...

Comment: Can you specify what exactly your issue is? The problematic cast you mention seems to work for me.

Comment: Yes the casting is basically good, now I see, but I cannot pass that way for the doSomethingElse method

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a value of type `Class<A>` can only be the class object for the exact class `A`, it cannot be any other class. The class object for some other class `B` would be `Class<B>`, and `Class<B>` is never a subtype of `Class<A>`. You probably want a `Class<? extends A>` parameter instead.

Second, your use of `.isAssignableFrom()` seems backwards (besides the fact that it's syntactically invalid as `B` is not a valid expression). `clazz.isAssignableFrom(B.class)` means that the class represented by `clazz` is a *superclass* of `B`, in which case it makes no sense to cast `clazz` to `Class<? extends B>`. You probably want `B.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` instead.

Once you make the first change above (make `clazz` type `Class<? extends A>`), the cast will compile, although it will be an unchecked cast. If you don't want an unchecked cast, instead of `(Class<? extends B>)clazz`, you can do `clazz.asSubclass(B.class)`.